# Existence of unbounded operators on Hilbert spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have been thinking about Hilbert spaces and I have realized that it is very difficult to find examples of unbounded linear maps between Hilbert spaces. One class of examples that can be constructed on any Hilbert space involves choosing a Hamel basis of unit vectors, mapping the members of the basis to arbitrarily large vectors in some other Hilbert space, and then extending the map linearly. This seems like a very pathological example. My questions are:

(1): If $V$ and $W$ are two Hilbert spaces can we construct an
unbounded linear map $\varphi:V \rightarrow W$ in some non-pathological way. I’m not exactly sure what non-pathological means but I would imagine it wouldn’t require the axiom of choice.

(2): Are there specific cases where the first question has a nice answer.

I am especially motivated by question (2) because in my functional analysis class we are studying everything great about bounded operators and I would really like to get an intuition for when I might run into the problem of having an unbounded operator between Hilbert spaces.

$\textbf{Note:}$ I have seen some notation before that refers to an unbounded operator defined on a subspace of a Hilbert space as an operator on that Hilbert space. This is not what I am looking for. I only care about operators defined on the entire Hilbert space.

Comment: The existence of a Hamel basis for every vector space does require the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you can find an Hyperplan $H$ which is not closed. Consider a linear function whose kernel is $H$, it is not closed

Comment: Is there any nice ways to find such a hyperplane if the space is nice in some way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two very natural and motivating examples of unbounded linear operators, namely multiplication and the derivative. Let's say our Hilbert space is $\mathcal{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and fix some $f\in \mathcal{H}$. It is clear that for all $g,h\in\mathcal{H}$ and for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ $$f\cdot(\lambda g+h)=\lambda f\cdot g+f\cdot h$$
Therefore $g\mapsto f\cdot g$ is linear. There is a sense in which this is *the* fundamental linear operator (see  [The Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) for rigorous details). However, the problem is that $f\mapsto f\cdot g$ is not a well-defined function $\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ since $\int |f(x)g(x)|^2dx$ need not converge, even if $\int |f(x)|^2dx$ and $\int |g(x)|^2dx$ both do individually.  For example, consider the measurable function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}&x\in(0,1)\\ 0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Then $f\in\mathcal{H}$, but $f\cdot f$ isn't.

A similar situation arises when we consider the map $f(x)\mapsto \frac{df}{dx}$. It is clearly linear (not to mention very natural in applications), but is not a well-defined function $\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H}$ for basically the same reason. This is a very non-pathological example of where unit basis vectors get mapped to arbitrarily large vectors, and thus extending by linearity runs into convergence issues. This essentially comes down to the formula for the power rule $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$$
Although $\{x^n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not literally a basis in the case of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, you should still think of the mapping of basis vectors $b_n\mapsto n b_n$ as being analogous to the action of the derivative on polynomials. A basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is given by the Hermite functions, which are each a polynomial times an exponential. Thus, the action of the derivative on basis vectors involves a product rule, so the explicit formula would be more complicated. Nevertheless, you end up mapping unit basis vectors to arbitrarily large vectors by applying the derivative.